# how to display images (base64 to bitmap) to Image Slider?

Tags: android, android-studio

can you give me some reference about `imageSlider` from `json`?
I can already convert `base64` to bitmaps using `listView`. but I am confused about how to display the results of the conversion into `imageSlider`.

```
data:[{"ID": 1,"Title": "Ads","Image":"data:image\/jpeg;base64........"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method can help:

```
private void setExistImage(ImageView imageView, String base64String){
    if (!base64String.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give a try to [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) they are most popular libraries used in Android nowadays